# The @Transactional annotation - class level and method level in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

Please consider the following case in Spring (I'm working with Spring 4.0.0 GA and Hibernate 4.3.5 final).

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public final class ChangePasswordDAO implements ChangePasswordService
{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager)
    {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public String getOldPassword(UserTable userTable)
    {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<String>criteriaQuery=criteriaBuilder.createQuery(String.class);
        Root<UserTable> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(UserTable.class));
        criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(UserTable_.password));
        criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root, userTable));
        List<String> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
        return list!=null&&!list.isEmpty()?list.get(0):null;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")        
    public boolean changePassword(String password, UserTable userTable)
    {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaUpdate<UserTable> criteriaUpdate=criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(UserTable.class);
        Root<UserTable> root = criteriaUpdate.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(UserTable.class));
        criteriaUpdate.set(root.get(UserTable_.password), password);
        criteriaUpdate.set(root.get(UserTable_.lastModified), DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC));
        criteriaUpdate.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root, userTable));
        return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaUpdate).executeUpdate()>0;
    }
}
```

In this case, I expect the following line

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

before the `changePassword()` method so that the class level `@Transactional` annotation can be overridden. Otherwise, the class level annotation uses `readOnly = true` is applied to this method too. Accordingly the update operation should not happen as the transaction is readonly.

How does Spring perform the update operation in this case then?

Comment: `readOnly` is only a hint for hibernate (and basically has nothing to do with Spring). It might decide to allow or disallow updates/inserts, however you are directly executing a query instead of using the entity manager to update the object. Your query will just execute where as an `entityManager.merge(userTable)` wouldn't do a thing. Also why are you doing everything with queries, that beats the purpose of an ORM tool...

Comment: Take a look at @Transactional read-only flag pitfalls section of http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1/index.html?ca=drs-

Comment: I use queries (criteria/JPQL) just because `entityManager.merge(entity)` requires an additional select query for the entity to be merged. Similarly, while deleting row/s from a database, we need extra checks prior to deleting a row. Otherwise an unexpected exception would be caused, if the entity to be deleted does not exist which in turn leads to unnecessary/redundant queries to be executed upon the database. This is tedious especially, when rows are deleted in a batch.

Answer (score 0):

Transactional annotation has to be in the services layer, not in the DAO layer.

Each DAO method should perform an operation so it does not make sense to use it in this layer.

If several operations are needed, the various DAO methods will be invoked from a service layer method.